# What happen after "./gradlew {package}-rpm"

Tags: gradle, bigtop

I am new to bigtop architecture, I would like to know
how does bigtop know the real build command to launch for this specific `package` after `./gradlew {package}-rpm`, I assume there must be some kind of configs define the real build command.  (The `package` is a maven based project)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Bigtop, but I am familiar with Gradle. See here for the Gradle task definition that you're referring to: https://github.com/apache/bigtop/blob/2d6f3dd7b7241aa2191c9ebc5a502a1415932464/packages.gradle#L460

The command that the task will execute is given under the `exec` directive: `rpmbuild <command>`. `command` is an array of arguments defined just above that directive. Most of its arguments are derived from the `config` object, which is basically a nested map (like a JSON object) produced by Groovy's [ConfigSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.2/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html), which reads the input BOM file as if it were a Groovy file.

So:

1. "Slurp" the BOM configuation into the `config` object
2. For each "component" defined within the `config` configuration, produce a set of tasks (`${package}-rpm` and others)
3. When configuring the `${package}-rpm` task, use the BOM configuration to derive the command arguments using the logic provided within the task closure
4. Upon execution, run `rpmbuild` with the aforementioned command arguments